# Create instance of object in main function

Tags: java, constructor, static

I am supposed to call the method `set` to make it change the attributes of the object I created, but is giving me the following error:

```
PrimerPrograma.java:34: error: non-static variable this cannot be
referenced from a static context
```

The code that I tried is:

```java
    public class PrimerPrograma{

      public class Punto{
         int x;          
         int y;

         public Punto(int lax, int lay){         
            x=lax;
            y=lay;       
         }
    
         public void set(int lax, int lay){                                   
            x=lax;
            y=lay;
         }

        public static void main(String[]args){
           Punto p=new Punto(5,5);
           p.set(8,8);
           System.out.println(p.x+p.y);
        }
    
    }
```

**How do I create an instance of the Punto class, so that I can call its methods?**

Comment: How did you put the constructor and p.set in the main method? Because that is indeed what you should be doing.

Comment: first of all thank you for answering, I will write how I put it first in the question

Comment: You are also new to this place. Please take some time to learn how it works. That starts with details such as: using the preview function to ensure that your input is **all** nicely formatted and indented. Instead of just dropping some code on us without clear problem descriptions and such.

Comment: I apologize, will try to make it better for next time I post, also thank you for your tips

Comment: And another thing: this isnt a discussion board. The idea is: you ask one precise question, and you get answers. You do **not** take the answer, modify your question, and have people help with the **next** problem you encouter. And: please do research. You are facing very basic problems that are explained all over this place, many times again. This community is not meant to hold your hand while you are doing trial and error with your first coding experiments.

Comment: And the reason why the above doesnt work is because you have an **inner** class. Why do yo want to use **two** classes here?!

Comment: well my professor told me I should put the two classes there, also I researched and did not know where to put the p.set and constructor, because in the main it was giving me a problem related to a non static value which cant be referenced from a static method, I will anyways follow are your tips @GhostCat and will try my best, I apologize

Comment: Then: A) either put each class in its own file or B) research how to have two classes in the same file (hint: only one can be public) or C) make that inner class static ... and: tell your instructor to be more precise in his requests to you folks. As there are various ways to have multiple classes, which obviously leads to confusion ...

Answer (score 1):

Put the instantiation, set and System print call inside your main function. I recommend follow step-by-step some youtube videos about the basic. This will help you much in the beggining.

Comment: While your answer may be correct, also adding an example (code) would probably help OP quite a bit.

Comment: thank you for answering, I will try to do so

Comment: If you could give me an example of the code it would really help, because by doing what you did it just says that non static variables cannot be referenced inside the static main, so yeah I really apreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

From [daniweb](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/405861/error-non-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context#post1733046):

> A non-static variable only exists when there is an instance of an
> object. If you have a static method, it can NOT get to any variable in
> a class object unless it has an instance of that class and uses that
> to get to the variable. For your inner class, change public to static
> if you want the main method to be able to reference it.

This code should work:

```
public class PrimerPrograma{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Punto p = new Punto(5, 5);
        p.set(8,8);
        System.out.println(p.x+p.y);
     }
     
     public static class Punto{
        int x;          
        int y;
        
        public Punto(int lax, int lay) {
            x = lax;
            y = lay;
        }

        public void set(int lax, int lay){
            this.x = lax;
            this.y = lay;
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901202/how-can-an-object-be-created-from-a-static-block) discussion.

Comment: thank you, the putting static in the class solved the problem, I looked into the discussion and it really helped me